# Mulesoft CloudHub integration with Prometheus

Tags: log4j, prometheus, mulesoft, cloudhub

I'm looking for some information in regards to integration of Mulesoft CloudHub and Prometheus.

Can the Log4j appender push logs ( runtime logs) to Prometheus server? is there a need for a parser tool such as Grok?

Any advise will be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Please clarify what is Prometheus in this context.

Comment: Prometheus is an open source Monitoring system & time series database.

Comment: Does Prometheus has a log4j2 appender? CloudHub doesn't implement third party log4j2 appenders, that's for sure.